# Quartz architecture Q - more or less jobs

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I am converting my Tomcat app to use the Quartz scheduler. I am using it mostly to trigger emailing processes in the background and I am concerned about overwhelming the processor with concurrent jobs. So  this is a best practices question.

Q) Is it better to spawn one quartz job (e.g. hourly) and have it call several routines serially? This way routine 2 will not start until routine 1 completes.

Or is it better to schedule each routine as a separate Quartz job and limit the number of threads?

What happens if there are more jobs scheduled that threads available. Do they just queue? i.e. can that be my controlling mechanism. I have already used directives to prevent concurrent identical jobs.

I don't want to have three similar jobs running simultaneously. It's not time dependent so serially is easier on the processor.

What is the most straight forward architecture?

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class HourJob implements Job, InterruptableJob {

    boolean interrupted = false;        
    String cls = this.getClass().getName();

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println(cls+"-Start");

        for(int i=1; i<15; i++){            

            try { //do work
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(interrupted){
                System.out.println(cls+"-Interrupted");
                return;
            }

        }//for

        System.out.println(cls+"-Exit"); 

    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
        interrupted = true;     
    }

}
```

and

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

...

sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
sched.start();

JobDetail hourJob  = newJob(HourJob.class ).withIdentity("hourJob",  "group1").build();

Trigger hourTrig = newTrigger()  
    .withIdentity("hourTrig", "group1")  
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 * * * ?")).build();

sched.scheduleJob(hourJob, hourTrig);
```

and

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

...

for(JobExecutionContext job : sched.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()){
    JobKey jK = job.getJobDetail().getKey(); 
    System.out.printf("Inerrupting %s\n", jK.getName());
    sched.interrupt(jK);
}
sched.shutdown(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From a design perspective I would recommend having each routine as a separate quartz job, if conceptually they are independent. This way if there is an error on one of them during running, the others execution and completion status will not be affected, you will be able to apply event listeners separately if you ever need any etc. Also you will be able to control each one's schedule independently.
- According to quartz documentation:

> **If you only have a few jobs that fire a few times a day, then one
>   thread is plenty**. If you have tens of thousands of jobs, with many
>   firing every minute, then you want a thread count more like 50 or 100
>   (this highly depends on the nature of the work that your jobs perform,
>   and your systems resources

Therefore you can only use one thread, and schedule your jobs to execute with separate schedules so that they do not trigger all at the same time.

- If however it happens that at the same time more than one jobs attempt to run and you have configured a number of threads less than the number of those jobs, then the ones that will not find a thread will be considered misfired:

> A misfire occurs if a persistent trigger misses its firing time
>   because of the scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no
>   available threads in Quartz's thread pool for executing the job.

Note that you can configure the time that a trigger will be configured misfired by changing the default misfire threshold value which is 30 secs. If a thread becomes available before that threshold, the trigger will execute without ever be considered misfired. On the other hand, regarding the misfired triggers, the misfire policy dictates what will happen:

> The different trigger types have different misfire instructions
>   available to them. By default they use a 'smart policy' instruction -
>   which has dynamic behavior based on trigger type and configuration.
>   When the scheduler starts, it searches for any persistent triggers
>   that have misfired, and it then updates each of them based on their
>   individually configured misfire instructions.

Default policy is different for each kind of trigger, but it usually runs the missed trigger as soon as a thread is available. In any case you need to see what the policy is for the trigger you use, and change it to the one you desire

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the information I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect answer, but this is what we did:
As we used Quartz to schedule many types of tasks, we didn't want a certain job to take to much resources thus affecting other jobs.

so we ended up splitting the process:
* The Quartz jobs just push the data into a job queue (different per job type)
* We configured execution services (easily scaled out) reading from the queue and doing the actual job (be it send emails, or other batch operations).

We now have over thousands of jobs running with no concurrency issues and are able to easily scale out per job type

Comment: I am actually doing that already. It's the jobs processing the queue I actually want to control. Today I'm doing it with Threads and it's getting a little complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand then:  
If its (the overload) in the quartz then you can configure how the trigger behaves by settings its MisFirePolicy (ignore missed runs, run now, etc.).  

If its (the overload) in the jobs reading from the queue, then it really depends on your apps business logic and isn't a question about Quartz, but your queue and your apps logic.